# Printing string array with for-loop doesn't function properly (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, sizeof

I'm a newcomer to C++ and was just trying to play around with several things, in this case specifically arrays. I wanted to print a string array to the console, but it either prints random things in binary, tells me I've got a segmentation fault or just does nothing.

The initial program was a bit more complex, but I tried to minimize the additional things as much as possible so I could see what the problem is, but with no success.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string stArr[] = {" 1 | ","_"," | ","_"," | ","_"," | "};
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(stArr); i++) {
           cout << stArr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the expected output was, obviously, the array. But what I usually get is something like: UH��AWAVAUATSH��(L�%�!I���#�E�K��H��v!H��H��%H�=�!�{�!I��H���I�����H�=_!�Q�!���t�H�D��A��D����;u��u�u���H�e�E1�H� [etc.]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what `sizeof(stArr)` returns?  If not, check it out.

Comment: This is why when doing C++ you should use `std::vector` or `std::array` and a proper enumerator. C-style `for` loops are fraught with peril.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition in the for loop

```
i < sizeof(stArr)
```

does not make sense. It does not provide the number of elements in the array.

At least you have to write

```
i < sizeof(stArr) / sizeof( *stArr )
```

For example if you have an array with `N` elements of type `T` then the size of the array is calculated using this formula

```
sizeof( array ) = N * sizeof( T )
```

So to get the number of elements in an array knowing its size and the size of its elements you can write

```
N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( T )
```

But it is much simpler to use the range-based for loop.

```
for ( const auto &s : stArr ) std::cout << s;
```

If your compiler supports C++ 17 then you could use the standard generic function `std::size` declared in the header `<iterator>`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string stArr[] = {" 1 | ","_"," | ","_"," | ","_"," | "};
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size( stArr ); i++) {
           cout << stArr[i];
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can use the structure `std::extent` defined in the header `<type_traits>` the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string stArr[] = {" 1 | ","_"," | ","_"," | ","_"," | "};
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < extent<decltype( stArr )>::value; i++) {
           cout << stArr[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(stArr)` gives you the *total byte size* of the whole array.  It does not give you the *element count*, which is what you are looking for.  As such, your loop is exceeding the bounds of the array, which is why you get garbage in your output.

To get the array's element count, you need to divide the array's byte size by the size of a single element in the array, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string stArr[] = {" 1 | ","_"," | ","_"," | ","_"," | "};
    int count = sizeof(stArr) / sizeof(stArr[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << stArr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, if you are using a C++17 or later compiler, you can use [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to get the element count of a static array:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    std::string stArr[] = {" 1 | ","_"," | ","_"," | ","_"," | "};
    size_t count = std::size(stArr);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << stArr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you are using a C++11 compiler, you can use [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {

    std::string stArr[] = {" 1 | ","_"," | ","_"," | ","_"," | "};
    size_t count = std::extent<decltype(stArr)>::value;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << stArr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That said, if you are using a C++11 or later compiler, consider using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main() {

    std::array<std::string, 7> stArr = {" 1 | ", "_", " | ", "_", " | ", "_", " | "};
    // or: in C++17 and later:
    // std::array stArr{" 1 | ", "_", " | ", "_", " | ", "_", " | "};

    std::size_t count = stArr.size();

    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << stArr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can alternatively use a [ranged-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string stArr[] = {" 1 | ", "_", " | ", "_", " | ", "_", " | "};
    // or std::array...

    for(auto &s : stArr) {
        std::cout << stArr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you are not using a C++11 or later compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> stArr;
    stArr.push_back(" 1 | ");
    stArr.push_back("_");
    stArr.push_back(" | ");
    stArr.push_back("_");
    stArr.push_back(" | ");
    stArr.push_back("_");
    stArr.push_back(" | ");

    std::size_t count = stArr.size();

    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << stArr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check, what is the value of `sizeof(strArray`). I bet you assumed it is 7 (i.e. the number of strings in the array).

Spoiler: well, it is most ceratinly not. `sizeof(strArray)` returns the amount of memeory occupied by the whole  array, that is 7 strings. It is a number larger than 7, thus during the iteration you read the memory outside of array bounds.

Divide it by the size of one element (e.g `sizeof(strArray)/sizeof(string)`) to get the size you are expceting.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I don't fully understand though: does sizeof(string) take the individual size of every string, or how exactly does it work? Because I didn't have to specify which string to take in consideration.

Comment: @splashrt Check what is the result of `sizeof(stArr[0])`, `sizeof(stArr[1])`, etc (that is - what `sizeof` returns for consecutive strings in your array) . Do those really differ? Compare it with the results of `stArr[0].length()`, `stArr[1].length()`, etc. In general you may think of `sizeof(string)` as a size (in bytes) of the thing that stores the information about the string, not the string itself.